# How to loop through div id's using JavaScript

Tags: html, loops, for-loop

I'm building a simple sudoku level checker. I need to loop through each lines,columns,each 3x3 boxes. In this code i have a first 3 numbers of first line. How i can loop trough id's numbers so i could check for a count of numbers inside first line?

```
<div id="firstline">
   <td width="30" height="30">
      <div id="1">
         <input class="one_number" maxlength="1" type="text" onkeypress='validate(event)'>
      </div>
   </td>
   <td width="30" height="30">
      <div id="2">
         <input class="one_number" maxlength="1" type="text" onkeypress='validate(event)'>
      </div>
   </td>
   <td width="30" height="30">
      <div id="3">
         <input class="one_number" maxlength="1" type="text" onkeypress='validate(event)'>
      </div>
   </td>
</div>
```

Comment: Loop using $.each function for a class name.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using jQuery for this. It's a javascript framework with alot of built in functionality, including what you need. You can download it [here](http://jquery.com/download/).

The looping can be achieved using a [selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) for the children of firstline and then looping through them using [the each function](http://api.jquery.com/each/).

Answer (score -1):

Loop through each, refer [this](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/).

```
  $('.one_number').each(function(){
    var theID = $(this).attr('id');   
    // Do whatever with each and stored the ID as var
  });
```

Comment: Who voted this down? Can you please explain why. This answers what the OP asked.